# Keep scroll-y after rerender

Tags: reactjs, scroll, redux

I have dropdown list with a lot of checkboxes, so this container has scroll. But when i click on any checkbox - it selects\deselects itself and then state changes.

So the problem is that after rerendering this container is back to the top. Is it possible to keep container's scroll after rendering without saving it to the state?

Comment: did you get a solution to this? i'm looking for the same thing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can save the "snapshot" of the scroll position before the commit phase.

[getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate) shows kind of what you are looking for.

The documentation example saves the current scroll position within `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` lifecycle method and then use the `snapshot` value passed to `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)` as the last argument to restore the scroll position.

It doesn't require creating a state to save the scroll position as you requested.

Comment: can u please give an example of using getSnapshotBeforeUpdate?

Comment: and this way is for react 16.3+ But i need for 15.4

Comment: May I ask why of `rendering without saving it to the state`?

Comment: Is it good practice to save scroll to the state? I just don't know

Comment: can you give me simple example that will help everyone

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you are re-rendering the complete list of the checkboxes.

There are 2 possible approaches:

1. Re-render only relevant checkbox
2. Save the scroll position of the container and update it once component is re-rendered.

Unfortunately, you haven't added any code examples, so can't share the code changes.